# How to setup a resident instance in google app engine?

Tags: php, google-app-engine

Can someone please tell me how can i setup resident availability instance. The problem is that I can't find anywhere that instance slider. I have setup billing and did enabled it in app.

Also you can see I have big latency in my app, no idea why.

One strange thing that I noticed is that my app engine dashboard is showing instances for same application and in Google Developers Console don't. You can see images attached
[image]

[image]

Comment: Might want to change the title of this question, doesn't seem mysql related...

Comment: Thanks for the tip, probably left from my earlier question

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want to create a [manually scaling class](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/#Python_Instance_scaling_and_class).